# Page scrolls to top when modal is opened issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have an issue with a modal that I programmed.  When it is opened or closed, it goes to the top of the page.  I want the page background to stay exactly where it is opened and not move.  I have it opening with JavaScript and have tried

```
$("html,body").css("overflow","hidden");
```

but it does not work.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a working example you could show us?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :-)  Since you're new here, most people here like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for demos.  Please try to strip it to the minimum that shows your problem.

Comment: Here is an example of my code that I am having problems with.  Figured it would be better in jsfiddle like suggested above [link](http://jsfiddle.net/b5XKb/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out (although not sure if it is the best way).  I replaced
`<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('function')">Open Modal</a>`

with
`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction('function')">Open Modal</a>`
I am up for better options if there are.